# How to make peanut butter less dry

Tags: peanut-butter

When I make peanut butter at home, in a food processor, it comes out reasonably creamy as in store bought peanut butter, but when I put it in my mouth, it sucks the moisture from my mouth and is too dry and hard to swallow.

How can I prepare it so that it is easier to consume and closer to store bought peanut butters. I tried adding a couple of spoons of oil. Would adding honey help?

Comment: Have you compared your ingredients to the ingredients on the label of store bought peanut butter?

Comment: Add more oil. Your food processor doesn't have the ability to crush peanuts to the extent required to make peanut butter without adding additional oil.

Answer (score 3):

Add refined peanut oil. Add more than a couple of tbsp. Add it generously. Try using peanuts from a different source.

Comment: What peanuts would you recommend

Answer (score 2):

Commercial peanut butter has added sugar and salt. Also emulsifiers to keep the oil from separating over time. Once I asked a friend why there was about a half inch of oil on their home-made peanut butter ; they said it is peanut oil and just needs to be stirred occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I use sustainable gourmet palm oil. I got it on Amazon. Smooth creamy peanut butter at room temperature, and oil doesn't separate, no need to refrigerate